# Sum of square roots of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

Is this always true?

$z^{1/2}+z^{1/2}=2z^{1/2}$

I said that it isn't in the multiform case but I want to justify this better (not just words).

Comment: Before using the word “true” in this context, you should define $x^{1/2}$ first.

Comment: If you are sensible enough to take the same square root each time...

Comment: Why's necessary? It's true if you define the square root but I'mt trying to say that is false if you don't define it.

Comment: @Verónica The square root function can be a bit ambiguous since you could be talking about $+\sqrt{z}$ or $-\sqrt{z}$, but this is confounded even more since in the complex plane, $a^b=\exp(b\ln(a)+2\pi n)$. So without defining exactly what you mean (or exactly what branch cut you mean), there's no way of knowing whether your equation holds.

Comment: @Verónica Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

For $z\neq 0$ we have $2$ distinct solutions

$$z^{\frac12}=w\implies w_1^2=z\quad w_2^2=z$$

and for any solution of course

$$w_i+w_i=2w_i$$

but

$$w_1+w_2=0$$